# Saving results of Async function for later use

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

I recently started learning node.js, my first ever approach to asynchronous functions but I just can't wrap my head around it. I'm pretty bad at explaining what I mean with words so I'll give an example.

In the code below I'm using the async library to loop through an array of twitter usernames and get their latest tweet(using the twitter library, the twit variable). All the tweets are collected in the results variable as an array that I can use in the last callback function. Similarity is a function I wrote, it just returns a number.

```
async.map(screenNames,function(name,callback){
    twit.get('/statuses/user_timeline.json', {screen_name: name, count : 1}, function(data) {
        callback(null,data[0]['text']);

    });
},function(err,results){
console.log(similarity(results));
});
```

Say now that I want to repeat this operation every X seconds using setInterval and each time check if the users have tweeted something new(ie if the tweet we just got is different from the one we have before) and if they have, store their new tweet and so on.
How can I store their tweets to compare them against the results of each iteration?

I tried doing the following with no success.

```
setInterval(function(){
    async.map(screenNames,function(name,callback){
        twit.get('/statuses/user_timeline.json', {screen_name: name, count : 1}, function(data) {
            callback(null,data[0]['text']);
        });
    },function(err,results){
    console.log(similarity(results));
    });
    console.log(results+'outside async');
},2000,[screenNames,similarity]);
```

Which resulted in "console.log(results+'outside async'); results is not defined"

Then I tried

```
setInterval(function(){
    async.map(screenNames,function(name,callback){
        twit.get('/statuses/user_timeline.json', {screen_name: name, count : 1}, function(data) {
            callback(null,data[0]['text']);
        });
    },function(err,results){
    console.log(similarity(results));
    });
    //console.log(results);
},2000,[screenNames,similarity]);
```

Which resulted in one correct iteration and then "callback(null,data[0]['text']);
cannot read property 'text' of undefined" (I'm pretty sure this is not entirely related though)

And finally

```
setInterval(function(){
    async.map(screenNames,function(name,callback){
        twit.get('/statuses/user_timeline.json', {screen_name: name, count : 1}, function(data) {
            callback(null,data[0]['text']);
        });
    },function(err,results){
    console.log(results);
    });
    console.log(results+'outside async');
},2000,[screenNames]);
```

Which resulted again in "console.log(results+'outside async'); results is not defined"

Can anyone point me to where I've done the mistake? Maybe the flaw in the way I approach this?
Thanks a lot for reading my question.

---

EDIT: It seems my similarity function somehow breaks the application. It's a pretty big function so I'll post a truncated version.

```
function similarity(phrases){
    if(phrases.length ==2){
    //Lots of stuff
    //concerning the phrases happen here
    // and a variable called similarity is produced which
    //contains a number
        return similarity;
    }else{
        throw "Can only find similarity between 2 phrases"; 
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first and third approach is bad, because results is just defined in the callback of async.map, so it's not defined in setInterval. I don't see what's the problem with your second, but anyway, I would just do this:

```
var screenNames = [initial data];
var lastTweets = null;
setInterval(function(){
    async.map(screenNames,function(name,callback){
        twit.get('/statuses/user_timeline.json', {screen_name: name, count : 1}, function(data) {
            callback(null,data[0]['text']);
        });
    },function(err,results){
      if ( lastTweets == null )
        lastTweets = results
      else
      for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++){
        if (lastTweets[i] != results[i] ) {
          // do something
          lastTweets[i] = results[i];
        }
      }
    });
},2000);
```

note that, if the screenNames array changes, than it'll be a problem for this, so I would put it into one object, like this:

```
var screenNames = [{name:'name', lastTweet:''},...];
setInterval(function(){
    async.map(screenNames,function(name,callback){
        twit.get('/statuses/user_timeline.json', {screen_name: name.name, count : 1}, function(data) {
            callback(null,data[0]['text']);
        });
    },function(err,results){
      for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++){
        if (screenNames[i].lastTweet != results[i] ) {
          // do something
          screenNames[i].lastTweet = results[i];
        }
      }
    });
},2000);
```

Comment: This works perfectly up until I try to use the function I wrote. It works correctly during the first iteration and breaks on the second with this error: "string is not a function". Any idea what might be causing this?

Comment: Nevermind, it turns out it is an unrelated problem, I'll post another question. Thanks a lot for answering!